# Where have google moved the latest gradle tool

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle

For new android studio tool with following build script

```
    repositories {
        mavenLocal()
        mavenCentral()
        google()
        jcenter()
    }

    // Switch the Android Gradle plugin version requirement depending on the
    // installed version of Gradle. This dependency is documented at
    // http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/version-compatibility
    // and https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-8143
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.0.1'
    }
}
```

I am getting following error.

A problem occurred evaluating root project 'android'.

> Could not resolve all artifacts for configuration 'classpath'.
> Could not find com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.0.1.
> Searched in the following locations:
> - https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/build/gradle/4.0.1/gradle-4.0.1.pom
> - https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/android/tools/build/gradle/4.0.1/gradle-4.0.1.pom
> Required by:
> unspecified:unspecified:unspecified

There website shows that we need to add google in buildscript, which is right there.
https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/gradle-plugin